# listing package and vbox warning

Tags: listings, verbatim, warnings

I have this many (see below) underfull warnings that are caused by using the listing package and creating `\begin{lstlisting}\end{}` to make code appear presentable.  Is there a may to fix the warnings?

I am using IEEETran document class and the `lstlisting` set up (see below).  Can this be adjusted to fix the issues?

```
\lstset
{
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=3,
  showstringspaces=false
}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{
  extendedchars = \true,
  language = {Python},
  frame = single,
  % ===========================================================                      
  framesep = 3pt,%expand outward.                                                    
  framerule = 0.4pt,%expand outward.                                                 
  xleftmargin = 3.7pt,%make the frame fits in the text area.                         
  xrightmargin = 3.5pt,%make the frame fits in the text area.                        
  % ===========================================================                      
  rulecolor=\color{Red}
}

\lstdefinestyle{B}
{
  style = Common,
  backgroundcolor = \color{Black},
  basicstyle = \scriptsize\color{White}\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{Orange},
  identifierstyle = \color{Cyan},
  stringstyle = \color{Red},
  commentstyle = \color{Green}
}
```

Warngins:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [4]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [5]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [6]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [7]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [8]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [9]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [10]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [11]
```

Comment: Please always post _complete_ document that shows the problem `\raggedbottom` before the listing will probably fix it though.

Comment: No but you could make a test file with a small page size a dozen lines of listing and one underfull box at a page break. That is the whole point of making a _Minimal_ example to make a reproducible test case on which to test possible answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\raggedbottom` worked.  You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no vertical flexibility between listing lines so if the text height is not an exact multiple of the line height (after taking account of the `\topskip` used for the first line) then you will get this warning (you would also get it in normal text if you had a full page with no paragraph break).

If you cannot change your `\textheight` you can add flexibility at the bottom of each page by using `\raggedbottom` before the listing.