# Beautifully format text of an external document

Tags: sourcecode, import

I have some formatted long text files looking like this:

```
f=50 k_max=420

 Iteration   Func-count     min f(x)         Procedure
     0            1      7.07212e-09         
     1            2      7.07212e-09         initial simplex
     2            4      7.06369e-09         reflect
     3            6      7.06369e-09         contract outside
     4            8      7.06369e-09         contract inside
     5           10      7.06367e-09         contract inside

Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
         - increase MaxFunEvals option.
         Current function value: 0.000000 

m=3.775
f=100 k_max=1009

 Iteration   Func-count     min f(x)         Procedure
     0            1      1.89961e-10         
     1            2      1.89961e-10         initial simplex
     2            4      1.33983e-10         expand
     3            6      8.33243e-11         expand
     4            8      7.98592e-11         contract outside
     5           10      7.98592e-11         contract inside

Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
         - increase MaxFunEvals option.
         Current function value: 0.000000
```

These files are the command line of `MATLAB` which are saved using `diary` command.

Is there a way to import the source file and typeset it beautifully in `LaTeX`? I love to use `minted` package or something comparable with colors if possible here.

Comment: @dustin,Is there some option there for plain Text file

Comment: Define beautiful.  Here are some possibilities: font; verbatim or not verbatim; in a box; in a tabular...  it is hard to see what you seek.

Comment: @rowman I added a screen capture from how I used it last.  Is the general idea?  I used it for code but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package, you can use

```
\inputminted[<options>]{<language>}{<file>}
```

Here's an example file `code.tex` using your sample file and saving it as `Mat1.m`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\inputminted[bgcolor=gray!10]{matlab}{Mat1.m}

\end{document}
```

The output, after processing with `pdflatex --shell-escape code.tex`:

[image]

With the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, you can use

```
\lstinputlisting[<options>]{<file>}
```

A simple example, again with the previous settings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
  keywordstyle=\color{green!40!black},
  columns=flexible
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=matlab]{Mat1.m}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to selectively set which words to be in color? Note that this is a text output so words like function or min should not be in color like MATLAB language.

Comment: @rowman Sure! Using the `listings` package, you can define your own settings. The package documentation has the details. I am not familiar enough with the `minted` package, so I wouldn't know how hard would be to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to one of my questions that has the listing environment.

[disregard the vbox warning stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113274/listing-package-and-vbox-warning)

Or you can use the verbatim package and it will look just like it is in-putted.

The listing environment is just a highspeed form of verbatim.

Here is what the code does but this is just an image of code formatting. Is this the general idea?  You can always adjust colors.

[image]

Useful links:

This is python based but the ideas are the same:

[how to highlight syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command)

This one is more general:

[code highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex#1985330)